# datasource failing to map to the transformed json using pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination, jquery-pagination

I am using [pagination.js](https://pagination.js.org/index.html) to load asynchronous data using below code snippet.

```
$('#demo').pagination({
    dataSource: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
    locator: 'items',
    totalNumber: 120,
    pageSize: 20,
    ajax: {
        beforeSend: function() {
            dataContainer.html('Loading data from flickr.com ...');
        }
    },
    callback: function(data, pagination) {
        // template method of yourself
        var html = template(data);
        dataContainer.html(html);
    }
})
```

As my json structure is different, I need to transform my json before mapping it to datasource, so I have changed the above code to as shown below:

```
$('#demo').pagination({
      dataSource: getTransformedJson(),
      locator: 'items',
      totalNumber: 120,
      pageSize: 25,
      ajax: {
        beforeSend: function() {
          container.prev().html('Loading products data ...');
        }
      },
      callback: function(response, pagination) {
        var dataHtml = '<ul>';
          console.log('response', response)
        $.each(response, function (index, item) {
          dataHtml += '<li>' + item.productName + '</li>';
        });

        dataHtml += '</ul>';

        container.prev().html(dataHtml);
      }
    })
  });
```

However in the callback,   `console.log('response', response)` always shows empty array `response []`, in the browser console. Below is my `getTransformedJSON()` function:

```
function getTransformedJson() {
      $.getJSON('./products.json', function(data) {         
        transformedData = data;
        totalCount = data['response']['totalCount'];
        transformedData['items'] = data['response']['results'];
        delete transformedData['response']["results"];
        console.log(transformedData);
          });

          return transformedData;
    }
```

But in my `getTransformedJson()` function, `console.log(transformedData);` shows the properly transformed json data.  Any fixes for this please.

Comment: $.getJSON is async. Your function is returning before $.getJSON is finished.

Comment: svela, how can i ensure function does not end before $.getJSON  is finished or how can make sure my datasource will be properly mapped the transformed json

Comment: Please find my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
dataSource: function(done) {
    $.getJSON('./products.json', function(data) {         
        transformedData = data;
        totalCount = data['response']['totalCount'];
        transformedData['items'] = data['response']['results'];
        delete transformedData['response']["results"];
        done(transformedData);
     });

          
 }
```

Comment: It is giving me the error, uncaught ReferenceError: done is not defined. can you please tell me what should that done definition should be

Comment: Have you included pagination.js correctly? https://jsfiddle.net/3ud6mfct/1/

Comment: ...or with the use of $.getJSON: https://jsfiddle.net/3ud6mfct/2/